# ToggleButtons and listeners in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, listener, togglebutton

I have this code

```
@FXML
private ToggleButton tb1;
@FXML
private ToggleButton tb2;
@FXML
ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

String cpuLoad1 ="D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk";
String cpuLoad2 = "D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/cpuLoad1.apk";   

@FXML
private void onToggleClick(){

    tb1.setUserData(cpuLoad1);
    tb1.setToggleGroup(group);
    tb2.setUserData(cpuLoad2);
    tb2.setToggleGroup(group);

    ChangeListener<Toggle> cLt = new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov,
                Toggle toggle, Toggle new_toggle){
            if (new_toggle != null){
                System.out.println(group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());

            }else{
                System.out.println("hello no");
            }
        }
    };

    group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(cLt);

}
```

Although I am still not using the userdata, the thing is that whenever I click the toggle button I get the desired output in increasing order.

Here is the output:

```
hello no                                                 //click2
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk    //click3
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
hello no                                                 //click4
hello no
hello no
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk    //click5
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
hello no                                                 //click6
hello no
hello no
hello no
hello no
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk    //click7
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk
```

In first click I get nothing.

From second click I start getting this kind of output. Could anyone explain this behaviour and provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the code from the `onToggleClick` method should go to the `initialize` method of the controller.

Now, on the first toggle click you set the data for the `ToggleButton`s and put them into the group and then you set the listener on the `ToggleGroup`.
So this listener will be executed only on the second toggle-click, where you set the data again and -even worse- you add an additional listener.

On the third click, these two listeners will be executed and you add another one ... hence the growing list of "... .apk" prints on the console.

All of these action should happen only once, after all of the nodes are created: this place is the `initialize` method of the controller.

---

If you would like to have independent `ToggleButton`s, simply do not put the `ToggleButton`s into a `ToggleGroup`, and then you can listen to the [`selectedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html#selectedProperty--) of the toggles separately:

```
ToggleButton tb1 = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton1");
ToggleButton tb2 = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton2");

tb1.selectedProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(tb1.getText() + " changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    System.out.println("Taking a nap!");
}));

tb2.selectedProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(tb2.getText() + " changed from " +oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    System.out.println("Working hard!");
}));
```

Alternatively you can also use the [`onActionProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty--).

```
for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++) {
    ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton"+i);
    tb.setUserData("UserData"+i);
    tb.setOnAction(e -> {
        System.out.println(tb.getText() + " - Selected: " + tb.isSelected() 
            + "; UserData: " + tb.getUserData());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.:)..It worked... Could you also tell that how can I access userdat after I click/toggle the button to on mode from off mode.

Comment: In your listener `new_toggle` contains the toggle which became selected in the group. If it is null, it means that no toggle is selected (the currently selected toggle is turned off).

Comment: state of one toggle button btn1(turned ON) changes(turns OFF) if clicked on another toggle button. Why?. How to manage this.

Comment: Because you placed the `ToggleButton`s in a `ToggleGroup`. That is exactly what the group does: only one toggle can be turned on at the same time, which will be the selected toggle for the group. If you want standalone toggles, just simly do not group them, and listen to their changes one-by-one.