# ToggleButtons in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, togglebutton

I have two toggle buttons.

1. I clicked on btn1      //btn1 is on; btn2 is off
2. I clicked on btn2      //btn2 is on;btn1 switches off automatically... why??

Can someone please explain this behavior and provide a solution.

I want all the toggle buttons to be independent.

Comment: It is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413313/togglebuttons-and-listeners-in-javafx. The answer is my last comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413313/togglebuttons-and-listeners-in-javafx/42413452#42413452 : Because of the `ToggleGroup`.

Comment: Could you forward some link regarding how to listen toggle action for buttons independently.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, if you do not put the `ToggleButton`s into a `ToggleGroup` you can listen to the [`selectedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html#selectedProperty--) of the toggles separately:

```
ToggleButton tb1 = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton1");
ToggleButton tb2 = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton2");

tb1.selectedProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(tb1.getText() + " changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    System.out.println("Taking a nap!");
}));

tb2.selectedProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(tb2.getText() + " changed from " +oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    System.out.println("Working hard!");
}));
```

**Update:** you can also use the [`onActionProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty--).

```
for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++) {
    ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton"+i);
    tb.setUserData("UserData"+i);
    tb.setOnAction(e -> {
        System.out.println(tb.getText() + " - Selected: " + tb.isSelected() 
            + "; UserData: " + tb.getUserData());
    });
}
```

Comment: But then I cant make the listener generic and use userdata of buttons in it. I'll have to do it for each button. I have upto 20 buttons.

Comment: Suppose I made the listener generic.. then how do I make it know that which button was clicked and whose userData to be used for further actions.

Comment: Updated the answer for you.